# What TV series has the longest opening credits?

Tags: credits

I'm used to opening credits on TV shows being relatively short. HBO's Westworld series has an opening credit sequence that is 1 minute, 40 seconds long. Is that the longest opening credit sequence for a TV series, or is there a series with a longer credit sequence at the start of every episode?

Comment: Don't let the silent downvoters get you down, I think this is a great question!

Comment: @Thunderforge Thanks! I was also waiting for someone to reference the YouTube video "Too Many Cooks", which is about a fictitious 80's sitcom and features an intro credit sequence that is about 15 minutes long. It's pretty funny.

Comment: A mere 1:40? How quickly we forget *Twin Peaks*' [2:30+ goodness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEGGQ958K_s)... ;)

Comment: @Walt OMG that's amazing! I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Sometimes I just sit and rewatch the Twin Peaks intro credits on repeat.

Comment: I vtc'd because this question does add any appreciation or understanding of the shows nor does it go into detail as to WHY these credit sequences are so long, but rather are merely just facts as the length.  As such, imho this question is trivia.

Comment: @DForck42 Well, knowing which shows have the longest sure makes me appreciate the shows more.

Comment: [Too Many Cooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrGrOK8oZG8) has an 11:12 intro, but the series was never aired. ;)

Comment: @jejorda2 Of course, [Wikipedia classifies *Too Many Cooks* as a short film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Many_Cooks_(short)) and it's done as a parody.

Comment: I was thinking that Boardwalk Empire has around 1:35 into, Game of Thrones is about 1:40, and True Blood is about 1:30, but Walt and Thunderforge have me way beat with that Twin Peeks opener!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The longest opening title sequence appears to be the Iranian TV show *[Zire Tigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zire_Tigh)* at **3 minutes 21 seconds!**

The longest English-language title sequence I can find is *[Twin Peaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks)* at about **2 minutes 36 seconds** (thanks to Walt for pointing it out in the comments).

Note that there are shorter versions of this opening as well (perhaps for syndication?) such as [this 1 minute 36 second version](https://youtu.be/X2lkvrMa27c) on CBS' official YouTube channel.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Well, +1 from me; however, Thunderforge, did you also follow the Iranian show?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Unfortunately I do not understand the language, so I have not seen *Zire Tigh*.

Comment: Fun fact: The average intro to a TV show (of the ones I  polled) seems to be 1:30

Comment: I believe the UK's (ITV) The Prisoner clocked in at three minutes (English language).  It incorporated story background, and generally used a new voice over - but in short - it was three minutes of reused footage at the beginning of most episodes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmgbiMf99NQ

Comment: @sonnik Can you confirm that the version you linked to is the version of the opening credits used in the majority of episodes? As it turns out, Wikipedia [has an article on the opening & closing scenes of *The Prisoner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_and_closing_sequences_of_The_Prisoner) and it notes that *"In "Arrival", the first episode of the series, the opening sequence is slightly longer and contains additional footage."* If this 3-minute version is the "normal" one, and not the special one from the first episode, then I'm fine adding that to the answer.

Comment: I linked to one from "Chimes of Big Ben" (episode 2).  I do recall the additional footage from Arrival, and it is not present in the version I linked to.  Thus, Arrival's opening length would be a bit longer than three minutes.  Only "Fallout" did away with the traditional opening altogether.  I'm midway through re-watching the series - so I'll confirm they didn't become more abbreviated later into the run of the show.